# Producing and Consuming OData XML in Java

Tags: java, odata, consumer, odata4j, producer

I am trying to build a producer and a consumer for generating OData based on a GraphML file.

Just using odata4j's example producer and consumer from XML, I receive the following error when trying to consumer their example file built by using their example producer.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid entity type XmlExample.Customers
      at org.odata4j.format.xml.EdmxFormatParser.resolve(EdmxFormatParser.java:146)
      at org.odata4j.format.xml.EdmxFormatParser.parseMetadata(EdmxFormatParser.java:82)
      at org.odata4j.consumer.AbstractODataClient.getMetadata(AbstractODataClient.java:44)
      at org.odata4j.consumer.AbstractODataConsumer$CachedEdmDataServices.refreshDelegate(AbstractODataConsumer.java:212)
      at org.odata4j.consumer.AbstractODataConsumer$CachedEdmDataServices.getDelegate(AbstractODataConsumer.java:205)
      at org.odata4j.internal.EdmDataServicesDecorator.findEdmEntitySet(EdmDataServicesDecorator.java:46)
      at org.odata4j.consumer.AbstractODataConsumer$CachedEdmDataServices.findEdmEntitySet(AbstractODataConsumer.java:221)
      at org.odata4j.consumer.AbstractODataConsumer.getFeedCustomizationMapping(AbstractODataConsumer.java:235)
      at org.odata4j.consumer.AbstractODataConsumer.getEntities(AbstractODataConsumer.java:73)
      at org.odata4j.consumer.AbstractODataConsumer.getEntities(AbstractODataConsumer.java:69)
```

Therefore when I implement a producer based on this example and attempt to consume it based on the consumer example, the same error arises.

Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Comment: provide some codes please

Comment: Have you checked your Producer?
Just open the OData URL manually with your browser or any other OData / Xml viewer.